# OrientDB etl with edge properties from json

Tags: json, properties, orientdb

I am using the instructions at http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Import-from-JSON.html to load a json file into orientdb. Everything of course works. I am now trying to add properties to edges and I really don't know how to change the input and the etl files to recognize edge properties.

I would like to have a property called "friendsSince" on the edge. People are discussing the edgeFields attribute when importing from csv but I am not sure how to use it when importing from JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You can use edgeFields in edge transformer. Example:

```
"edge":{
   "class":"Account",
   "joinFieldName":"friends",
   "lookup":"Account.id",
   "direction":"out",
   "edgeFields": { "YOR_PROPERTY": "${input.YOR_PROPERTY}" },
   "unresolvedLinkAction":"NOTHING"
}
```

Comment: That works for csv, but I need json. what is $input?

Comment: The other problem is: what if I have multiple edges coming out of vertex, each with different properties?